# How to automatically Start google speech recognition on my page?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, webkit, speech-to-text

I wrote a HTML5 webpage consisting only of:

```
<input type="text" style="font-size: 40px;"  name="speech" size="50"  x-webkit-speech/>
```

What I'm trying to do is to get the x-webkit-speech to start automatically as soon as I enter the page and continously put out the speech recognition results into the text. How would I do  that ? I've seen various javascripts relating to that and I tested a lot of them but they don't work for me.

Thanks to anyone who answers ! ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to use [Web Speech API](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/speechapi.html), for example:

```
if ('webkitSpeechRecognition' in window) {
  var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
  var final_transcript = '';
  recognition.continuous = true;
  recognition.interimResults = true;

  recognition.onresult = function( event ) {
    var final_transcript = '';
    for (var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; ++i) {
      if (event.results[i].isFinal) {
        final_transcript += event.results[i][0].transcript;
      } 
    }
    document.getElementById( 'speech' ).value = final_transcript;
  };
  recognition.start();
}
```

The only one thing is that you will need to allow page to use microphone at page load

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LE5r3/1/)

Comment: I added your code to my html file but I still can't get it to work, I was thinking that chrome blocks my microphone ,but, I have my settings set so it would ask me for permission and the microphone itself works because I try it on my simple HTML input and when I click the microphone button it starts listening. it seems like that javascript doesn't do anything. Maybe I put in the JAVA incorrectly ? I placed your code in between <script type="text/javascript"> </script> In the body and it didn't work ,then, I moved it to the Head and it still didn't work. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @ShadyProgrammer and jsFiddle demo is working for you? Have you looked into console, are there any errors? Are you using latest Google Chrome browser?

Comment: jsFiddle is working. I'm only using notepad++ so I don't know of any errors. I'm using the latest Google chrome.

Comment: In your Google Chrome open console and look inside the result.

Comment: The console displays no errors. I noticed google chrome definitley blocks my microphone for my page and it doesn't ask for permission I try to change it bit its still being blocked

Comment: Maybe this is happen because you run your script from HTML file and not from server. Try to setup some localhost server or upload your page to the hosting.

Comment: I Found a way to set up a local host using python 'SimpleHTTPServer' command and I was able to load my page from chrome, it asked me to allow my microphone usage and I allowed, in the tab I had the red recording sign meaning that Something was being recorded but still no text appeared in my input box :(

Comment: @ShadyProgrammer what language are you using? Does jsFiddle works for you?

Comment: jsFiddle works for me, I'm using Python for that simpleHTTPserver

Comment: I found what the problem was Javascript -> document.getElementById( 'speech' ) ....... My HTML file -> name="speech". I had to change the 'name' of the input to 'Id' . It works now but it is very slow. Thanks for all your help man !

Comment: no problem ;) don't forget to accept answer if it was helpful and welcome to SO!

Comment: How to refresh the page after the speech recognition stops ? Because the speech recognition is set to continuous but it will eventually stop.

I've tried adding:

if(recognition.onned = true)
{
location.reload(true);
};

But it doesn't work

Comment: You have a typo there, should be `onend` instead of `onned`, also this is not a property, this is an event handler so should be just: `recognition.onend = function() { location.reload( true ) };`

Comment: Thanks again gentleman, works perfectly now. I'm having a lot of trouble understanding javascript and how the code flows, Why did you have to add the 'function()' for this code to work ?

Comment: You can read more about event handlers here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers